# How can I get a variable in C to be used in a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, c

I have a temperature sensor hooked up to a Raspberry Pi, I am able to read and printf the temperature. What I am trying to do next is to get the values from the sensor and have them get logged into a MySQL database.

Everything works, except, I can not figure out how to format the MySQL insert Query to use the f variable and the h variable that is generated by the read_dht_data() function and pass it to the MIA_temp_insert(float f, float h).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define MAX_TIMINGS 85
#define DHT_PIN     3   /* GPIO-22 */

int data[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
float temp_f;

static char *host = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX";
static char *user = "XXX";
static char *password = "XXX";
static char *dbname = "XXX";

unsigned int port = 3306;
static char *unix_socket = NULL;
unsigned int flag = 0;

static  MYSQL *conn; //Needed to be static so all of the functions can draw from it

void MIA_mysql_connection()
{
    // Connecting to the Database

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);

    if (!(mysql_real_connect(conn, host, user, password, dbname, port, unix_socket, flag)))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n Error: %s [%d] \n", mysql_error(conn),mysql_errno(conn));
        exit (1);
    }

    //Connected
    printf ("We Are Connected \n");
}

void MIA_mysql_close()
{
    //Closing Connection
    mysql_close(conn);

}

void MIA_temp_insert(float f, float h)
{

    //Inserting into MySQL Table
    if(mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO `temperature` (`id`, `Date`,`Time`, `Temperature`, `Humidity`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '%f' , '%f')") !=0)
{
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit (-1);
    } else {

        printf("Rows were insert \n");
    }   

}

void read_dht_data()
{
    uint8_t laststate   = HIGH;
    uint8_t counter     = 0;
    uint8_t j           = 0, i;

    data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = data[3] = data[4] = 0;

    /* pull pin down for 18 milliseconds */
    pinMode( DHT_PIN, OUTPUT );
    digitalWrite( DHT_PIN, LOW );
    delay( 18 );

    /* prepare to read the pin */
    pinMode( DHT_PIN, INPUT );

    /* detect change and read data */
    for ( i = 0; i < MAX_TIMINGS; i++ )
    {
        counter = 0;
        while ( digitalRead( DHT_PIN ) == laststate )
        {
            counter++;
            delayMicroseconds( 1 );
            if ( counter == 255 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        laststate = digitalRead( DHT_PIN );

        if ( counter == 255 )
            break;

        /* ignore first 3 transitions */
        if ( (i >= 4) && (i % 2 == 0) )
        {
            /* shove each bit into the storage bytes */
            data[j / 8] <<= 1;
            if ( counter > 16 )
                data[j / 8] |= 1;
             j++;
        }
    }

    /*
     * check we read 40 bits (8bit x 5 ) + verify checksum in the last byte
     * print it out if data is good
     */
    if ( (j >= 40) &&
         (data[4] == ( (data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]) & 0xFF) ) )
    {
        float h = (float)((data[0] << 8) + data[1]) / 10;
        if ( h > 100 )
        {
            h = data[0];    // for DHT11
        }
        float c = (float)(((data[2] & 0x7F) << 8) + data[3]) / 10;
        if ( c > 125 )
        {
            c = data[2];    // for DHT11
        }
        if ( data[2] & 0x80 )
        {
            c = -c;
        }
    float f = c * 1.8f + 32;

    //printf( "Humidity = %.1f %% Temperature = %.1f *C (%.1f *F)\n", h, c, f );
        printf ("Temp of the room is : %.1f \n",f);

        //Insert Data into MIA Temperature Table
         MIA_temp_insert(10.0,11.1);

    }else  {
        //printf( "Data not good, skip\n" );
    }
}

int main ()
{
    printf( "Raspberry Pi DHT11/DHT22 temperature/humidity test\n" );

    if ( wiringPiSetup() == -1 )
        exit( 1 );

    while ( 1 )
    {
    MIA_mysql_connection();
    read_dht_data();
    delay (1000);
    MIA_mysql_close();
    printf("End of program \n");
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You can't just put `printf()` format specifiers directly into the query string for `mysql_query()`.  You could use `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` to write the format string -- with the formatted numbers instead of format specifiers -- into a buffer... then pass that as your query string.

Comment: @Dmitri is there an advantage over using sprintf() or snprintf()? I got the code working with a sprintf(). After you posted the reply I was able to get some code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `printf()`-style format specifiers in `mysql_query()` directly as you have above.  Instead, you can use `sprintf()` or `snprintf()` to write the format string -- with the formatted numbers instead of format specifiers -- into a buffer... then pass that as your query string.

So in `MIA_temp_insert()`, instead of the following:

```
if(mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO `temperature` (`id`, `Date`,`Time`, `Temperature`, `Humidity`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '%f' , '%f')") !=0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit (-1);
    /* ...etc... */
```

...you could try this:

```
/* Your original query string, with the %f specifiers */
const char *formatstring = "INSERT INTO `temperature` (`id`, `Date`,`Time`, `Temperature`, `Humidity`) VALUES (NULL, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_TIME(), '%f' , '%f')";

/* snprintf() the query into a buffer, to fill in the numbers */
char buf[256]; // should be large enough for the query with the numbers filled in
if (snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), formatstring, f, h) >= sizeof(buf))
{
    exit(-1); // if snprintf() returned sizeof(buf) or more, buf was too short
}

/* call mysql_query() with the formatted query from the buffer */
if (mysql_query(conn, buf) != 0)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit (-1);
    /* ...etc... */
```

Comment: is there an advantage over using sprintf() or snprintf()? I got the code working with a sprintf(). After you posted the reply I was able to get some code to work.

Comment: @user3525621 The advantage of `snprintf()` over `sprintf()` is that it lets you limit the length of the string it will write so that it won't write past the end of your buffer.  `sprintf()` is okay only if you know, for certain, that after the format string is expanded it will still be smaller than your buffer.

Comment: is there a way to check the buffer size of the format string? So I know what to set my buffer if I want to use sprint()?

Comment: @user3525621 There's really no good reason to use `sprintf()` instead of `snprintf()`.  To find the needed buffer size you can: add the length of your format string minus the length of the format specifiers within it, plus the maximum possible lengths the formatted values might expand to, plus the null terminator; Or, you can call `snprintf()` with a short buffer (even a single char) and use the return value + 1 to get the size needed (`snprintf()` returns the number of characters it *would have* written, if it had enough room).

Comment: thank you for the explanation and help. One more question related to it, would this also work for UPDATE and SELECT Queries?

Comment: @user3525621 Yes, you can run other types of queries this way... but of course you'll need other functions to deal with any data retrieved by the query.

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I was about to get the INSERT and UPDATE query to work. But now I am having issues with using SELECT to get the results of a cell and save it as a variable. Got any help/tips?

Comment: @Vlad How to get/handle the results from a SELECT query might be a bit much to explain in comments here... but if you try a web search for "mysql c tutorial" you'll find some good examples.

Comment: I was able to get some code and after playing with it for a while I got the code to compile, but every time I call the function with the new code, I get an error 139. And I have no idea why.